# Reformatting date in MYSQL for output in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I have a ROW in my database's table that is a TYPE = timestamp. So the saved date format is like this:

> 2015-11-30 14:54:04

I googled it and said this is default timestamp format of MYSQL. How can I echo this date in PHP using this format:

> November 30, 2015 2:54:04 PM

Note: I am running this in a loop and the retrieved data includes this date in the whole table so the var for this date to echo is `$feeds->reg_date`. I hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$dt = "2015-11-30 14:54:04";
$unixdatetime = strtotime($dt);
$formatted_date = strftime("%B %d, %Y %I:%M:%S %p",$unixdatetime);
echo $formatted_date;  // output: November 30, 2015 02:54:04 PM
```

**Edited:**

```
$unixdatetime = strtotime($feeds->reg_date);
$formatted_date = strftime("%B %d, %Y %I:%M:%S %p",$unixdatetime);
echo $formatted_date;
```

**Re-edited**

```
if(DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $feeds->reg_date)){
    $unixdatetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $feeds->reg_date)->getTimestamp();
}else{
    $unixdatetime = strtotime($feeds->reg_date);
}
$formatted_date = strftime("%B %d, %Y %I:%M:%S %p",$unixdatetime);
echo $formatted_date;
```

Comment: Thanks! What if this is the date format saved 14/11/2015 20:49:22?

Comment: I mean, I have a different table with a row that has this format of date, 14/11/2015 20:49:22. How can I output this in this format using PHP, November 14, 2015 8:49:22 PM?

Comment: @PaoloMedina This will work if the datetime is saved in MySQL format i.e Y-m-d H:i:s. Since you're fetching the datetime from the database, it should work fine for you.

Comment: It has a wrong output of date. To clarify: `14/11/2015 20:49:22` = `dd/mm/yyyy 08:49:22 PM`.

Comment: I tried the above `strftime("%B %d, %Y %I:%M:%S %p",$unixdatetime)`, --> result: January 01, 1970 12:00:00 AM. The saved date in the database is this `14/11/2015 20:49:22`.

Comment: @PaoloMedina I've updated my answer. Please see the **re-edited** section of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a php syntax such as Date('m-d-y')); you just need to change the format of how you want the date to be displayed by using that function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `date()` and `strtotime()`

```
$date = date('F d, Y h:i:s A', strtotime($row["date"]));
```

Check this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for more date format.